# How many days should I wait for e-mail of Prospective Supervisor in this condition

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, etiquette, france

I am a citizen of an Asian country who e-mailed a prof in France 4 weeks  ago that I am interested in discussing PhD research opportunity in Pure mathematics.

He replied 2 weeks ago asking me to send him my master's thesis and my bachelor's and master's transcript. I sent him that the same day.

How many days I should wait for his reply? I know prof's are really busy and he must have a lot of work to do. But certainly I think it is only my responsibility if he has not replied anything after a give time to remind him.

> So, what do you think how many days I should wait  for his reply and what exactly should I write in remainder e-mail( which don't come off as rude)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its been a couple of weeks you could ask whether he has any additional guidance for you based on what you sent him. You could also ask what further steps it is appropriate for you to take at this time.

Don't expect a reply, however, for a couple more weeks. And there is no particular reason to push on dates unless deadlines are approaching.

But two weeks or so is probably about right for a follow up. Keep it short and easy to reply to.